# console.log(json2[key2].id) undefined

Tags: json, node.js, undefined

I have this node.js code:

```
var json2 = JSON.parse(body2);
console.log(json2)

var arrFound2 = Object.keys(json2).filter(function(key2) {
    console.log(json2[key2].id)
    return json2[key2].id;
}).reduce(function(obj2, key2){
    obj2 = json2[key2].attempts[0].duration;
       console.log(obj2)
       return obj2;
}, {});
//console.log(arrFound);
callback(null, arrFound2);
});
```

When I run it the `console.log(json2)` returns the json but `console.log(json2[key2].id)` returns undefined. What had I done wrong here?

Here is my JSON:

```
{ id: 'local-1517179209543',
  name: 'TeraGen (5MB) 30146960-047c-11e8-afb5-17a9edeb2d55',
  attempts: 
       [ { startTime: '2018-01-28T22:40:07.941GMT',
       endTime: '2018-01-28T22:40:17.739GMT',
       lastUpdated: '2018-01-28T22:40:17.000GMT',
       duration: 9798,
       sparkUser: 'paulcarron',
       completed: true,
       endTimeEpoch: 1517179217739,
       startTimeEpoch: 1517179207941,
       lastUpdatedEpoch: 1517179217000 } ] }
```

Comment: Please check `console.log(json2[key2])`

Comment: Could you add the json that is printed

Comment: Try this - `console.log(json2[key2][id])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do :

Instead of passing `return json2[key2].id;` you just need `return json2[key2];`

Run the snippet and you will get the idea

```js
var json2 = { 
  id: 'local-1517179209543',
  name: 'TeraGen (5MB) 30146960-047c-11e8-afb5-17a9edeb2d55',
  attempts: 
       [ { startTime: '2018-01-28T22:40:07.941GMT',
       endTime: '2018-01-28T22:40:17.739GMT',
       lastUpdated: '2018-01-28T22:40:17.000GMT',
       duration: 9798,
       sparkUser: 'paulcarron',
       completed: true,
       endTimeEpoch: 1517179217739,
       startTimeEpoch: 1517179207941,
       lastUpdatedEpoch: 1517179217000 } ] };
console.log(json2);

var arrFound2 = Object.keys(json2).filter(function(key2) {
    console.log(key2 , ' -----> ', json2[key2]);
    return json2[key2];
}).reduce(function(obj2, key2){
    obj2 = json2[key2].attempts[0].duration;
       console.log(obj2)
       return obj2;
}, {});
//console.log(arrFound);
callback(null, arrFound2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(json2[key2].id)` is wrong because filter function passes the array to the callback function. You are chaining filter function on Object.keys(json2) which means the filter function would get keys of the json2 object.
To get values of JSON you will have to simply use `json2[key2]`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/filter-method-array-javascript